# Julia: How delete multiple rows by index from a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'd like to know how I can permanently delete multiple rows from a dataframe in Julia.
Here is the dataframe example:

```
    Group   Variable1   Variable2
String  Float64 Float64
1   B   -0.661256   0.265538
2   B   0.111651    0.837895
3   A   0.197754    0.987195
4   A   1.35057 0.696815
5   A   -1.20899    0.496407
6   B   0.813047    0.324904
```

I'd like to delete rows 2, 4, and 6 from my dataframe. There is an easy function to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to delete inplace:

```
delete!(df, [2, 4, 6])
```

In case you want a new df without the selected rows:

```
df[Not([2, 4, 6]), :]
```

Answer (score 3):

As of DataFrames.jl version 1.3, `delete!` has been deprecated and replaced with `deleteat!`. This change was made to more correctly reflect the difference between `Base.delete!` and `Base.deleteat!`. You can compare [the docstring](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.deleteat!) for `Base.deleteat!` to [the docstring](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.delete!) for `Base.delete!`. In fact, the DataFrames `deleteat!` function is a method extension of `Base.deleteat!`.

Here's an example of using `deleteat!` on a data frame:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:4, b=5:8)
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      5
   2 │     2      6
   3 │     3      7
   4 │     4      8

julia> deleteat!(df, [2, 3])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      5
   2 │     4      8
```

Here's the DataFrames documentation for `deleteat!`:

https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.deleteat!